# How to change file in windows CE 6 folder

Tags: windows, windows-ce

I need to change dwui_scanner.xml file in /Windows directory, but this file is read only and I can't change this parameter in file properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **binmod** utility to modify this xml file in nk.bin. When you need to re-flash OS image.
[see how to use binmod here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2009/05/16/platform-builder-replacing-files-in-an-nk.bin-with-binmod.exe.aspx)